# Changing Application Title in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to change the title of my application when it loads. I want to be able to make it so that instead of having it separately in a different private sub, I want to be able to make it load in my main private sub so that I can avoid having to contact the web server twice.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim Details As String()

    Try
        Details = wc.DownloadString("http://(IP GOES HERE):8080/launcher/Details.php").Split("#")
        wc.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to connect to server. Please make sure you're connected to the internet.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Server Connection Failed")
        Return
    End Try

    Me.Text = Details(7)

End Sub
```

I use the same function in my main private sub for another thing so if I could put it there the code would be more efficient.

Comment: create a function in main and put the code and store the reslut in global variable then use it which place you want.

Comment: can you show the code in your other private sub to see similarities and differences between both calls? and maybe refine your question? if the result is stored in a global variable, as SATSON says, isn't it solved then?

Comment: Basically what I want to do is change the title of my application on the top of the application bar. Instead of creating a new private sub for the form I want to add it in my button private sub so that I don't need to recall the previous things. I updated my original post with the other sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim CommDetails As String()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()

    Try
        CommDetails = wc.DownloadString("http://(IP GOES HERE):8080/launcher/Details.php").Split("#")
        wc.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to connect to server. Please make sure you're connected to the internet.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Server Connection Failed")
        Return
    End Try

    Me.Text = CommDetails(7)

End Sub
```

in your other Sub:

```
    some_text = CommDetails(7)
```

Comment: That would still be connecting to the web server. I don't want it to do it twice.